# While hadoop installation "jps" showing nothing

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have installed hadoop version `2.9.2`, after starting all services `jps` command shows no output.

I am not able to find out why this is happening even `start-dfs.sh` shows namenode,datanode,secondary namenode started but nothing displays.

Comment: If you run start-dfs.sh as sudo user then you should check jps as sudo user.

Comment: JPS shows only processes for your current session user

Comment: Thank you but it may be ssh key problem.